# Angular $log using console.group / groupEnd

Tags: javascript, angularjs, logging

I'm a great fan of using Angular's services to do things in my Angular application. So it seems like a natural choice for me to use `$log` for logging. It has many benefits over `console.log()` like the way I can omit debug-logging in a production situation.

One thing I regret, though, and I wonder if I can overcome this. I used to use `console.group` / `console.groupCollapsed` and `console.groupEnd` in my application to clean up my console when debugging iterators.

I tried the following decorator, but it's not even close (and certainly no cigar) to the desired behavior:

```
app.config([ '$provide', function($provide) {
  // Use the `decorator` solution to substitute or attach behaviors to
  // original service instance; @see angular-mocks for more examples....

  $provide.decorator('$log', [ '$delegate', function($delegate) {
    // Save the original $log.debug()
    var debugFn = $delegate.debug;

    $delegate.debug = function() {
      var args    = [].slice.call(arguments),
      now     = new Date(),
      logtime = now.getHours() + ':' + now.getMinutes() + ':' + now.getSeconds() + '.' + now.getMilliseconds()

      // Prepend timestamp
      args[0] = logtime + ' - ' + args[0];

      // Call the original with the output prepended with formatted timestamp
      debugFn.apply(null, args)
    };
    $delegate.group = function() {
      var args    = [].slice.call(arguments),
      now     = new Date(),
      logtime = now.getHours() + ':' + now.getMinutes() + ':' + now.getSeconds() + '.' + now.getMilliseconds()

      // Prepend timestamp
      args[0] = ' --> ' + args[0];

      // Call the original with the output prepended with formatted timestamp
      debugFn.apply(null, args)
    };


    return $delegate;
  }]);
}]);
```

Is there a way to get Angular `$log` to mimic this behavior any better?